# Failed to load bundle (ios) after upgrading to react native 0.59.10

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm getting some issues when I upgrade my project from 0.55.4 to 0.59.10. It can be built successfully but after that I shows node server error.

Here is my AppDelegate.m before upgrading. It's okay. The app run as I expected.

```
#import ...

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //some codes here...

    NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSString *url = @"http://localhost";
    url = @"http://192.168.2.125";

    NSString *urlBody = @":8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true";
    NSString *urlFull = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url, urlBody];

    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:urlFull];

    #else
        jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    #endif

    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Cloud9"
                                                      initialProperties:nil
                                                      launchOptions:launchOptions];

    //some codes here...
}

//some codes here...

@end
```

And here is the AppDelegate.m after upgrading to 0.59.10

```
#import ...

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //some codes here...

    RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Cloud9"
                                                      initialProperties:nil
                                                      launchOptions:launchOptions];

    //some codes here...
}

//some codes here...

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    #if DEBUG
        NSString *url = @"http://localhost";
        url = @"http://192.168.2.125";
        NSString *urlBody = @":8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true";
        NSString *urlFull = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url, urlBody];

        return [NSURL URLWithString:urlFull];
    #else
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
}

@end
```

It shows this error
[image]

And this is my ip address

[image]

Am I missing something? Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by these steps:

1. rm -rf ios/build/
2. kill $(lsof -t -i:8081)
3. react-native run-ios